# DWH and Bigdata testing tools

Tags: testing, bigdata, data-warehouse

I am looking for good testing tools for Data ware house / Big data tools in the market and its features. I have to validate the source and target data, logic etc. and to reduce the testing effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Querysurge, Informatica DQM.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a CI/AT (Continuous integration/Automated Testing) system, that for the testing aspect, you build source and target extracts of various types, and store them in a reconciliation database, which has automated tests run across it after every load.

So the beauty of it is, once it is setup, new scripts can be added for every "test case" that you come across. The idea is that every night after all devs have submitted their code into TFS/GIT/etc., then an auto deploy fro mthe code repository occurs to a test box, which then loads a set of test data through the system end-to-end, exercising the load process and database fully, from a logical data point of view. Any failures are seen the next day, rather than waiting for the next deployment cycle.

I know my suggestion involves lots of work, but once set up, it is extensible and very powerful. This is equally applicable for SQL and NoSQL environments.